# Lint Error with to.Fixed(2)

Tags: javascript

So the problem I am having is that whenever I try to make the to.Fixed(2); at the end of my g_fTotal I get a lint error and it also doesn't show up in the txtTotal field. IT shows up in the filed when I take the toFixed off but I need to have the total show only two decimal points. What am I doing wrong here?

```
// DO IT: Assign the total to the txtTotal textbox.  Include a dollar sign and use .toFixed() to display 2 decimal places

        document.getElementById("txtTotal").value = "$" + g_fTotal.toFixed(2);
```

This is the whole code below.

```
// DO NOT DELETE ANYTHING IN THIS FILE

/*jsl:option explicit*/
/*jsl:declare $*//*jsl:declare addEventListener*//*jsl:declare isDigits*//*jsl:declare alert*//*jsl:declare blur*//*jsl:declare clearInterval*//*jsl:declare clearTimeout*//*jsl:declare close*//*jsl:declare closed*//*jsl:declare confirm*//*jsl:declare console*//*jsl:declare Debug*//*jsl:declare defaultStatus*//*jsl:declare document*//*jsl:declare event*//*jsl:declare focus*//*jsl:declare frames*//*jsl:declare getComputedStyle*//*jsl:declare history*//*jsl:declare Image*//*jsl:declare length*//*jsl:declare location*//*jsl:declare moveBy*//*jsl:declare moveTo*//*jsl:declare navigator*//*jsl:declare open*//*jsl:declare opener*//*jsl:declare opera*//*jsl:declare Option*//*jsl:declare parent*//*jsl:declare Number*//*jsl:declare parseInt*//*jsl:declare print*//*jsl:declare prompt*//*jsl:declare resizeBy*//*jsl:declare resizeTo*//*jsl:declare screen*//*jsl:declare scroll*//*jsl:declare scrollBy*//*jsl:declare scrollTo*//*jsl:declare setInterval*//*jsl:declare setTimeout*//*jsl:declare status*//*jsl:declare top*//*jsl:declare window*//*jsl:declare XMLHttpRequest*/



// Constants (Constants are variables that never change throughout the running of your program. They are almost always declared globally.)
var gc_fSandwichPrice = 5.99; // Price for each sandwich (Version 1 and 2 only)
var gc_fExtrasPrice = 1.50;  // Price for each extra item

// GLOBAL VARS

// Global object vars
var g_divErrors;
var g_radSandwich;
var g_radSize;
var g_chkExtras;

// Other global vars
var g_fTotal;
var g_sSandwich;
var g_sSize;
var g_sExtras;


// DO IT: Hook up an event handler for window.onload to the Init function.

window.onload = Init;

function Init() {

    // DO IT: Change the version number in the line below, if necessary, so it accurately reflects this particular version of Dirty Deli.

    document.getElementById("h1Title").innerHTML = "Dirty Deli 1.0";

    // DO IT: grab and assign any html objects you need to work with

    g_divErrors = document.getElementById("divErrors");
    g_radSandwich = document.getElementsByName("radSandwich");
    g_radSize = document.getElementsByName("radSize");
    g_chkExtras = document.getElementsByName("chkExtras");

    // DO IT: Set the innerHTML of spanExtrasPrice to gc_fExtrasPrice.  Tip: Use the .toFixed() method to display it with 2 decimal places

    document.getElementById("spanExtrasPrice").innerHTML = gc_fExtrasPrice.toFixed(2);

    // DO IT: Hook up any event handlers you need

    document.getElementById("btnCalculateTotal").onclick = CalculateTotal;
    document.getElementById("btnProcessOrder").onclick = ProcessOrder;

    // Version 2
    // DO IT: You need to hook up an event handler that runs whenever the user selects a different Payment option.  
    //This is the "onchange" event.  I suggest you use an anonymous function, and make use of the *selectedIndex* property to see if they chose the credit card.  
    //This function will check to see if the user selected the Credit card option.  If they did, set the CSS visibility property to "visible", otherwise set it to "hidden".


  document.getElementById("selPayment").onchange =
        function() {
            var divCreditCardInfo = document.getElementById ("divCreditCardInfo");

            if (document.getElementById("selPayment").selectedIndex === 2) {
                divCreditCardInfo.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
            else {
                divCreditCardInfo.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        };

} // function Init()

// function Init


function CalculateTotal() {

    // this function should be called when the user clicks the Calculate Total button.  Its purpose is mainly to, well, calculate the total.  Remember to hook up an appropriate event handler so this function will be called when they click.

    // DO IT: clear out divErrors (set the innerHTML to an empty string)

        g_divErrors.innerHTML = "";

    // DO IT: Tip: you're going to be adding to g_fTotal.  Remember: adding anything to garbage will always give you garbage.  So how do you prevent this error?
    // Same deal for g_sExtras.

        g_fTotal = 0;
        g_sExtras = " ";

    /*  DO IT:
        Sandwich code - Version 1
        Using an IF statement, see which radio button they checked, and assign the value of the selected sandwich to a global var name g_sSandwich.
        If nothing is selected, set divErrors to "Select a sandwich", and exit the function.

        Sandwich code - Version 2
        Within each IF statement remove the line of code you wrote for Version 1.  
        Replace it with a call to a function (that you will write) named GetSandwichName().  
        When you call this function, pass it one parameter - the index of the radSandwich radio button that the user checked.  
        More info on the function itself is given below.
    */

    /*  if (g_radSandwich[0].checked === true) {
            GetSandwichName(0);
        }
        else if (g_radSandwich[1].checked === true) {
            GetSandwichName(1);
        }
        else if (g_radSandwich[2].checked === true) {
            GetSandwichName(2);
        }
        else if (g_radSandwich[3].checked === true) {
            GetSandwichName(3);
        }
        else {
            g_divErrors.innerHTML = "Select a sandwich";
            return;
        }

 */

    // Version 3
    /*  CONVERT: Sandwich code
        Using a FOR loop and a single IF statement within the loop, see which radio button they checked. 
        When you find it, set g_sSandwich to the sandwich name 
        and break out of the loop using the break command.
        If nothing is selected, set divErrors to "Select a sandwich", and exit the function.
        But how do you know if nothing was selected?  Use a boolean variable in the If statement, 
        then check its value after you get out of the loop.
        Remember: Your code should be flexible enough so that if the number 
        of sandwiches change, your code can still work.  
        Afterall, that's one of the reasons we're using a loop.
        Do NOT call the GetSandwichName() function.  Incorporate its code here, and remove it.
    */

    var iChecked = false;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < g_radSandwich.length; i++) { 
        if (g_radSandwich[i].checked) { 
        iChecked = true;
        g_sSandwich = g_radSandwich[i].value; 
        break; 
        } 
    } 

    if (iChecked === false) {
        g_divErrors.innerHTML = "Select a sandwich"; 
        return;
    }


    // Version 1
    /* DO IT:
        This is the Size code.
        Make sure they selected a size.
        Update the total by adding the price of a sandwich (which is already declared as a constant) to the total
        If nothing is selected, set divErrors to "Please choose a size", and exit the function.

        Tip:  An If Statement is the key here.
    */

    // Version 2
    /*
        In this version, the sandwiches are not all the same price.  
        The price of each sandwich is contained within the title attribute of the radSandwich radio button for that sandwich 
        (take a look at the html to verify this).
        So, modify the IF statement from Version 1.  You need to call a function (that you will write)  named GetSizeUpdateTotal().  More on that below.
    */
/*  

    if (g_radSize[0].checked === true) {
        GetSizeUpdateTotal(0); 

    }
    else if (g_radSize[1].checked === true) {
        GetSizeUpdateTotal(1);  

    }
    else if (g_radSize[2].checked === true) {
        GetSizeUpdateTotal(2); 

    }
    else {
        g_divErrors.innerHTML = "Please choose a size";
        return;
    }

 */

    // Version 3
    /* CONVERT: Size code
        Once again, using a FOR loop and a single IF statement within the loop, 
        see which radio button they checked, get the price and update the total just like you did previously.  
        Then break out of the loop using the break command.

        If nothing is selected, set divErrors to "Please choose a size", and exit the function.
        Do NOT call the GetSizeUpdateTotal() function.  Incorporate its code here, and remove it.
    */

    iChecked = false;
    var price;

    for (i = 0; i < g_radSize.length; i++) { 
        if (g_radSize[i].checked) { 
        iChecked = true;
        price = g_radSize[i].title;
        price = price.substr(1);
        price += Number(price);
        g_sSize = g_radSize[i].value;
        g_fTotal += price;
        break; 
        } 
    } 

    if (iChecked === false) {
        g_divErrors.innerHTML = "Please choose a size"; 
        return;
    }




    /* DO IT:
        "Extras" code - Version 1
        Using an IF statement, see which extra(s) they checked. For each extra selected, do the following:
        Concatenate the value of the selected extra to a global var name g_sExtras.
        Update the Total with the price of the Extra.


        "Extras" code - Version 2
        Remove each IF statement you wrote for Version 1.  Replace it with a call to a function (that you will write) named GetExtraUpdateTotal().   
        When you call this function, pass it one parameter - the index of the chkExtras checkbox that the user checked.  
        More info on the function itself is given below.
    */

    GetExtraUpdateTotal(0);
    GetExtraUpdateTotal(1);
    GetExtraUpdateTotal(2)


    // Version 3
    /* CONVERT:  "Extras" code
        Again, using a FOR loop and a single IF statement within the loop, do what needs to be done.  Remember NOT to break out of the loop when you find a checked checkbox (there may be more).
        Do NOT call the GetExtraUpdateTotal() function.  Incorporate its code here, and remove it.
    */


    /* ****** That's it -- you're done with the loops. ******* */
    // END Version 3



    /* DO IT:
        Optional fun: Remove the trailing comma on the last extra.
        HINT: use the length property and the substr() method.
    */


    // Version 1
    // DO IT: Assign the total to the txtTotal textbox.  Include a dollar sign and use .toFixed() to display 2 decimal places

    document.getElementById("txtTotal").value = "$" + g_fTotal.toFixed(2);


} // function CalculateTotal


// Version 2
/* DO IT:
    Declare function GetSandwichName().
    This function takes one parameter, named p_iSandwichIndex, 
    which is a radSandwich radio button index, i.e. the index of the Sandwich they selected.
    It assigns the value of the selected sandwich to a global var name g_sSandwich.
*/
// END Version 2


// Version 2
/* DO IT:
    Declare function GetSizeUpdateTotal().
    This function takes one parameter, named p_iSizeIndex, which is a radSize radio button index, 
    i.e. the index of the radSize radio button that they selected.
    The function should assign the *value* of the selected size to a global var name g_sSize.
    Also, it must update the Total with the price for the size they selected.  
    The price is located in the title attribute of the radio button (take a look).
    Remember that (using dot notation) you can access any object attribute you want, once you grab the object.
    But the price in the title attribute contains a dollar sign, 
    and you want everything AFTER the dollar sign.  
    Use the substr() method to get the entire string, starting with the SECOND character in the string. 
    Look back on our class notes to see how we did this.
    Use an alert to see that you got what you intended.
    Then, convert that string to a number and add it to the Total.

    TIP:  Declare local vars as necessary.
*/




// Version 2
/* DO IT:
    Declare function GetExtraUpdateTotal().
    This function takes one parameter, named p_iExtraIndex, which is a chkExtras checkbox index, i.e. the index of an extra they selected.
    Use an if statement to see if this particular checkbox is checked.  If it is, then do the following:
    Concatenate the value of the selected extra to a global var name g_sExtras.
    Update the Total with the price of the Extra.
*/

function GetExtraUpdateTotal(p_iExtraIndex) {
    if (g_chkExtras[p_iExtraIndex].checked === true) {
        g_sExtras += g_chkExtras[p_iExtraIndex].value + ", ";
        g_fTotal += gc_fExtrasPrice;
    }   

}


function ProcessOrder() {

    // This function should run when the ProcessOrder button is clicked.


    // Version 2
    // DO IT: declare any local vars you may need
    var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");
    var txtMonth = document.getElementById("txtMonth");
    var selPayment = document.getElementById("selPayment");
    var selYear = document.getElementById("selYear");
    var txtCreditCardNbr = document.getElementById("txtCreditCardNbr");

    var month;


    // Version 2
    // DO IT: Before you do your error checking, does anything need to be initialized to an empty string?  Now's the time to do it.
    document.getElementById("divOrder").innerHTML = "";
    g_divErrors.innerHTML = "";


    // Version 2
    // DO IT: If the name field is blank, display "Enter customer's name", set the focus and get out.

    if (txtName.value === "") {
        g_divErrors.innerHTML = "Enter customer's name";
        txtName.focus();
        return;
    }   

    // Version 2
    /* DO IT: Credit Card Code
        Use an IF statement to determine if the user selected the credit card option in the selPayment dropdown
        If they did, you need to do the following:
            if the credit card number field was left blank or the contents of the field is not a number, display (in divErrors) the message shown in the working version, put focus on the card number field and get out.

            if the month field was left blank or the contents of the field is not a number, display the message shown in the working version, put focus on the month field and get out.
            if the month they entered is less than 1 or > 12, display the message shown in the working version, put focus on the month field and get out.
            TIP:  Remember to convert the txtMonth value to a number before you do your comparison.

            if they neglected to select a year, display the message shown in the working version, put focus on the year field and get out.
    */
    // END Version 2

    // The following section I got assistance from another classmate. 

    if (selPayment.selectedIndex === 2) {
        if ((txtCreditCardNbr.value === "") || (isDigits(txtCreditCardNbr.value) === false)) {
            g_divErrors.innerHTML = "Enter your card number using only digits";
            txtCreditCardNbr.focus();
            return;

        } else if ((txtMonth.value === "") || (isDigits(txtMonth.value) === false)) {
            g_divErrors.innerHTML = "Enter month using only digits";
            txtMonth.focus();
            return;

        } else {
            month = Number(txtMonth.value);
            if ((month < 1) || (month > 12)) {
                g_divErrors.innerHTML = "Enter month between 1 and 12";
                txtMonth.focus();
                return;             
            }
        }
        if (selYear.selectedIndex === 0) {
            g_divErrors.innerHTML = "Please select a year";
            selYear.focus();
            return;             
        }




    }


    // DO IT: Concatenate the appropriate msg into divOrder.  The Welcome msg is within an h3 tag.  Every other line is within a p tag.  The last line is in bold.
    /* Version 1:
        Do not include the user's name in the welcome message.
        Do not include the "Paid by" statement.
    */


    /* Version 2:
        Include the user's name in the welcome message.
        Include the "Paid by" statement.
    */
    document.getElementById("divOrder").innerHTML =
    "<h3>Welcome to Dirty Deli!</h3>" + txtName.value + "<br>" +
    "You have ordered a " + g_sSize + " " + g_sSandwich + " with " + g_sExtras + "<br>" +
    "Your total is " + document.getElementById("txtTotal").value + "<br>" +
    "Paid with " + selPayment.value + "<br>" + "<br>" +
     "<strong>Have a nice day!</strong>";



} // function ProcessOrder
```

Comment: try parseFloat before toFixed like parseFloat(g_fTotal).toFixed(2)

Comment: What do you mean by "link error"?

Comment: lint error sorry. Whe I post the code, I get a lint error about a missing semicolon.

Comment: `toFixed` is a method of `Number` object. You have to ensure `g_fTotal` is a number.

Comment: That is right! The parseFloat did work but I complete forget to make sure to use the number method. Thank you!